# char* new and delete [] error when a string is assigned

Tags: c++, memory, runtime-error, new-operator, delete-operator

I need a C++ refresher. Why does this gives a memory exception?

```
pear = new char[1024];
pear = "happy go lucky";
delete [] pear; // exception
```

Comment: is the first line equal to `char* pear = new char[1024];` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
pear = new char[1024];
```

Memory for 1024 character is allocated from heap and `pear` points to the start of it.

```
pear = "happy go lucky";
```

`pear` now points to the string literal which resides in the read-only segment and the previously allocated memory is leaked.

```
delete [] pear;
```

You try to free the read-only string, which is a undefined behaviour manifested as a runtime exception.

Answer (score 5):

> pear = "happy go lucky";

This *replaces* the pointer allocated by `new char[]`. So now your `delete[] pear` tries to free the statically allocated string.

That's bad. You can only `delete` what you allocate with `new`. And since you overwrote (and lost) that pointer, you can't `delete` it.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is assigning `pear` to an allocated array of chars on the heap, and then reassigning it to point to the string which is in a static location. If you try to delete that it will error because you're not supposed to delete stuff in that static location.